# How can I update my view with sorted lists of movies after button press in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On my lists show page, I display the movies that belong to that list. I have a button that, when pressed, should sort the movies in that list by title. I think I'm on the right track, but I can't seem the get the view to update after the button is clicked.

Here is my list.rb model where I've defined an order_list method:

```
  def order_list(sort_by)
    if sort_by == 'title' || sort_by.blank?
      self.movies.order(title: :asc)
    elsif sort_by == 'rating'
      self.movies.order(rating: :asc)
    else
      self.movies.order(created_at: :asc)
    end
  end
```

And here is my controller action for lists#show:

```
  def show
    @list.movies.order_list(params[:sort_by])
  end
```

I've also made sure to include the `:sort_by` in my permitted params.

And finally, here's my `link_to` button on the show.html.erb for my lists:

```
<%= link_to "Sort By Title", list_path(sort_by: 'title'), class: 'btn btn-secondary btn-sm btn-space' %>
```

My show.html.erb:

```
<div class="container-fluid text-center">
  <h2><strong><%= @list.name %></strong></h2>
</div>

<div class="text-center">
  <h2><strong><% @list.average_rating.to_i.ceil.times do %></strong></h2>
    <span><%= fa_icon "star" %></span>
  <% end %>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid text-center">
  <span>
    <%= link_to "Sort By Title", list_path(@list.id, sort_by: 'title'), class: 'btn btn-secondary btn-sm btn-space' %>

    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-space btn-secondary" id="sort-ratings">Sort By Rating</button>
  </span>
</div>


<div class="card-deck text-center" id="card-deck">
  <% @list.movies.each do |m| %>
      <div class="card">
        <img src="<%= m.poster %>" alt="No poster found." class="card-img-top">

        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title"><%= m.title %></h5>
          <p class="card-text"><%= m.genre %></p>
          <p class="card-text">Director: <%= m.director %></p>
          <p class="card-text"><%= m.plot %></p>
        </div>

        <div class="card-footer">
          Rating: <% m.rating.times do %>
            <span><%= fa_icon "star" %></span>
          <% end %>

          <div class="btn-top">
            <span class="btn-group">
              <%= button_to "Edit movie", edit_movie_path(m), method: 'get', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-space' %>

              <%= button_to "Delete movie", movie_path(m), method: 'delete', controller: 'movies', class: 'btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-space', data: { confirm: "Are you sure?"} %>
            </span>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

  <% end %>
</div>
```

The idea is that when the button is pressed, sort_by: 'title' is passed into my params, then I call the order_list method on my movies in that list, and then the view is updated with a sorted list. As of right now, the params look good when the button is clicked, but the view isn't updating. What am I missing? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling `list_path` helper you need to pass list id as an argument. See [the docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers). Additional params are allowed, but after required ones.

Changing your link to:

```
<%= link_to "Sort By Title", list_path(@list.id, sort_by: 'title'), class: 'btn btn-secondary btn-sm btn-space' %>
```

should fix it.

The other problem, in your controller you call `order_list` method for `movies` collection of the list, whereas it is defined for `List` model itself. I think you need to change it to `@list.order_list(params[:sort_by])`

One more thing: you call `order_list` method but does not use its result. So sorted movies are just wasted. To fix it you need to store it to instance variable and reuse in the view:

```
@movies = @list.order_list(params[:sort_by])
```

Comment: I made the changes you requested and the same thing is still happening. The button is pressed but no sorting happens. Any other ideas?

Comment: Check if the browser really send a request when you press the button. Then check server logs to see which Paramus are passed to the controller.

Comment: The browser is sending a request and in the server logs, here are my params:=> <ActionController::Parameters {"sort_by"=>"title", "controller"=>"lists", "action"=>"show", "id"=>"7"} permitted: false>

Comment: Started GET "/lists/7?sort_by=title" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-10-07 18:08:19 -0400
Processing by ListsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"sort_by"=>"title", "id"=>"7"}

Comment: I think it's updating, but since sorted movies are not passed from controller to view the results is the same. Please share your view btw.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. In the view you fetch movies with ```@list.movies```. Every time this call returns the same list, in the same order. To fix it replace it with ```@movies```, where ```@movies``` is initialized in the controller as I wrote in the answer.

Comment: This automatically updates the view to have them sorted by title. I only want them to be sorted by title on the click of the button. If I do it as you described, the titles are sorted already upon traveling to the list_path. How can I set it up to have it only sort on click?

Comment: So change code of the ```order_list(sort_by)``` method then. Initially it is called with ```sort_by.blank?``` option - in this case return unsorted list of movies.

Comment: I figured it out. I had to remove the `|| sort_by.blank?` from my `order_list` method. Thanks for working with me!

Comment: No probs, glad to help. I'd appreciate if you mark my answer as useful